# How can I emit an event in the websocket request-response sampler in jmeter?

Tags: events, websocket, jmeter

I am passing this :-
wss://staging-api.klipsocial.com:443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjMwZjUzNGIxLWNmMzMtMTFlYi1hOGI0LWU3ZTFjYzRhZDViZCIsInNlc3Npb24iOiIxNGI3ZGQxMC1kMzNhLTExZWItYmI0ZS1kOWVlOGQ0NjEyMDQiLCJ0eXBlIjoiMSIsImlhdCI6MTYyNDM1MzE5NywiZXhwIjoxNjM5OTA1MTk3fQ.8RQoPC6UJZXHAtl54tLBIofla5n46zWeZ9IKA2AXvns
(using existing connection)

Request data:
["chat_events", {
"action": "send_message",
"room_local_id": "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf",
"participants": ["39344260-cf33-11eb-a8b4-e7e1cc4ad5bd"],
"messages": [ {
"message": "Hi How are you?",
"local_id": "asdfasdfasdf",
"content_type": 0
} ]
}]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what do you mean by "emit an event", just capture the request from the real browser using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and make sure that JMeter sends exactly the same request (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

More information:

- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)
- [socket.io-chatserversample.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/socket.io-chatserversample.jmx)

Answer (score 0):

This works, [rasa_socket_io.jmx](https://github.com/ourdaidai/test_rasa_socket_io/blob/5796abb896e4304dde8236aef7f6c3fdd16b91dc/rasa_socket_io.jmx)

Open it in jmeter. Check variables defined in Test Plan.

Update 2022/3/28:

1. Install those plugins: **WebSocket Sampler by Maciej Zaleski**
   and **WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch**
2. You can choose "**WebSocket request-reponse Sampler**" or "**WebSocket Sampler**". (Basic usage of these sampler. Check [here](https://octoperf.com/blog/2021/11/25/jmeter-web-sockets/#websocket-open-connection))
3. Main process is:

> 1. Get *sid* with **HTTP Request**. Save *sid* to variable.
> 2. "session_request" with **HTTP Request**
> 3. Open connection with **WebSocket Open Connection**
> 4. Send "2probe" and receive "3probe" with **WebSocket request-reponse Sampler**
> 5. Send "5" to receive "session_confirm" and *session* with **WebSocket request-reponse Sampler**. Save *session* to variable.
> 6. Read "6" with **WebSocket Single Read Sampler**.
> 7. Send your message alone with *session* with **WebSocket request-reponse Sampler**.

This question is asking "How to configure jmeter to emit event?".
There is no "**CODE**" to solve this.
And I post my jmeter test plan above.

Comment: Please share any relevant code in the Question, as a [minimal, workable example (mwe)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not all users will click on links and therefore won't be able to help reproduce, and solve, your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).